# Why is the bottom Instance rotated wrong?

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes, faces, normals

does anyone know why the bottom face of my object doesn't rotate correctly? It's supposed to look like the one in the second picture, but for this face it won't work. Changing the Capture Attribute from Face to Point worked, but I'm trying to make this a fractal and it's not working with multiple iterations. Any ideas on how to fix this?

[image: Wrong face]

[image: correct face]

[image: node tree]

Comment: I think you are only aligning the Z axis of the instance with the normal of the face and then rotating it 60º but that's not aligning the X or Y with any normal so you are starting with the default orientation, which in the bottom face's case will probably be different. I think you need another Align to Euler to vector with for another axes. I'm pretty sure I've seen this on a youtube video, I'll see if I can find it

Comment: *"It's supposed to look like the one in the second picture"* - and doesn't it?

Comment: @Cornivius After a lot of testing it sound like this could be it. PPlease let me know if you find it

Answer (score 0):

What version are you on? It seems to work on 3.5.1:
[image]

Are you sure the bottom face is an equilateral triangle? If one of the sides is slightly longer the normals might not be what you expect

Comment: This maybe the problem. I couldn't get a perfect triangle, it's off by 0.001 degrees. It also seems to work by rotating the y-axis by 0.01 degrees, which is not really a pretty solution

Comment: I made that pyramid with a 3 sided cone. Then with the edge length setting ON, I lowered the top vertex in edit mode until all the edges were the same length as the base. It's not really a precise method with just 2 decimals on the length but maybe the resulting mesh works better with that node set up than what you did to make yours.
I find it weird that there isn't an 'Add tetrahedron' button or at least a checkbox to make a pyramid heigh consistent with the side length

Comment: Thank you, it is weird. So, i made it work with this, but my instance object is a little different and sadly it won't work with that. But thank you very much for your help!